How can I revoke Terminal's access to dragged-in folders?
I intentionally do not grant the standard macOS Terminal app "Full Disk Access".
What I had done recently, in order to access a folder's contents that Terminal normally could not access with this setup, is dragged that folder into the terminal window. This copies the path of the folder and also grants access to that folder (which, in this case, is a removable drive.)
However, I cannot now find a way to revoke access to that folder.
I've tried removing Terminal from Settings → Privacy & Security as well as using "tccutil" to "reset All" for "com.apple.Terminal"—both options clear out the standard Files & Folder allow lines for Terminal, but do not do anything to revoke access to these specific folders.
Is there a way to revoke access to folders that were dragged into Terminal?

TBH, I can't see that this is a security vulnerability of any kind -- unless there are already loads of other holes in the wall. Is the disk encrypted?

@benwiggy My intent in this case was just temporary access. In any case, how much disk access Terminal should have can get to be a pretty heated topic that I'd rather not get into.  I'd like to stick to figuring out how to revoke the action taken by this particular feature.

The action granted the app a security-scoped bookmark.

There’s no supported user-level way to revoke such a bookmark.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/739198

This was also what I was starting to think was the case. I wish I could find where Terminal would be keeping them. I've scoured ~/Library for anything that looks like one, and purged anything Terminal-related regardless (including Preferences, Saved Application State, and sharedfilelist), and even though Terminal's prefs get reset, it still has that access.

While sandboxed apps can save security-scoped bookmarks to preserve a grant by user interaction (such as dragging), Terminal is actually not sandboxed (you can see this by adding the "Sandbox" column to Activity Monitor). In cases that I have been able to observe (i.e. files or folders on the boot drive), Terminal uses the com.apple.macl xattr on the file or folder.
Jeff Johnson discovered this back in Catalina; this behavior is still observable in Sequoia. Removing this xattr is still not as easy as using xattr -d because, as Howard Oakley notes, SIP will immediately restore the attribute. However, several workarounds exist, including rewriting a new file with the contents of the old file (!).
In the case of dragging the "Downloads" folder into Terminal, which leads to the "com.apple.macl" xattr being applied to that folder, the workaround I used is:

Reboot into macOS Recovery.

Start Terminal, and mount the Data drive.

Find the "Downloads" folder, and use xattr -d com.apple.macl Downloads.


When it comes to removable volumes, however, there is no obvious com.apple.macl xattr (or indeed any change) being made to the volume. What does work is erasing the volume in question—which is a rather nuclear option, to be sure.
